# Why Alchemy responds eth_getBlockByNumber with wrong data

Tags: polygon, alchemy

Network: Polygon Mainnet.

I am using the Alchemy RPC in the following manner: I listen for new blocks and then retrieve block data, including transactions, based on the block number. However, today my production code encountered an issue where Alchemy provided an incorrect response for block [#43618876 (0x299923c)](https://polygonscan.com/block/43618876).

The Alchemy dashboard has acknowledged this problem by fixing the incorrect data in their logs:
[image]

Block hash value `0x2f7880d...` that was initially provided is not valid for the block in question, and the block only contains one transaction.

I have now made a manual request and received the correct response, which includes the correct block hash `0x72f69ea...` and the corresponding set of transactions:
[image]

My question is: what could have caused this bug to occur? Additionally, what would be the best approach to handle such situations in the future?

P.S.
I have already checked the information on https://polygonscan.com/blocks_forked but did not find any details regarding block forks for block `#43618876` or its nearest blocks.
[image]

P.P.S.
Block is dated by Jun-07-2023 02:13:41 AM +UTC and the buggy RPC response is dated by Jun-07-2023 02:13:57 AM +UTC - 16 seconds after it.